# happynumber code Time Limit Exceeded issue

Tags: python-3.x

**The problem is :** 
Write an algorithm to determine if a number n is "happy".

A happy number is a number defined by the following process: Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers.

Return True if n is a happy number, and False if not.

**My solution is below.**

```
class Solution:
    def isHappy(self, n: int) -> bool:
        flag = True
        while flag:
            try:
                result = self.passExam(n)
                if result == 1:
                    flag = False
                else:
                    self.passExam(result)
            except:
                return False
        # print('passed')
        return True

    def passExam(self, n: int) -> int:
        result = 0
        list = str(n)
        # Loop through indices in n
        for i in range(len(list)):
            # print(f'{i}th : {list[i]}')
            # Store a square number
            num = int(list[i])
            num = num * num
            result = result + num
        # print(f'result is {result}')
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def isHappy(self, n: int) -> bool:
        sum = self.passExam(n)
        seen = set()
        flag = True
        while flag:
            if sum in seen:
                return False
            elif sum == 1:
                return True
            else:
                seen.add(sum)
                sum = self.passExam(sum)


    def passExam(self, n: int) -> int:
        result = 0
        list = str(n)
        # Loop through indices in n
        for i in range(len(list)):
            # print(f'{i}th : {list[i]}')
            # Store a square number
            num = int(list[i])
            num = num * num
            result = result + num
        # print(f'result is {result}')
        return result
```